# Trying to install RGoogleDocs package?

Tags: r, installation

I am trying to download and also upload files to a shared folder on Google Drive using R. As a first step I am trying to install the package `RGoogleDocs`. Here is my R command to install the package:

```
install.packages("RGoogleDocs", repos = "http://www.omegahat.org/R", type="source")
```

I am getting this error:

```
'unable to access index for repository'
'cannot open URL'
```

Is this the right repository URL that I am using to install `RGoogleDocs` package?

Comment: I would try `devtools::install_github("duncantl/RGoogleDocs")` as [it seems to be on GIthub](https://github.com/duncantl/RGoogleDocs). You'll need the `devtools` package to run that command.

Comment: if you know the location or URL of `RGoogleDocs` package's `zip file` , you can try `install_url()` or `install_github()` functions from `devtools` package

Answer (score 1):

Just need to run the 4 lines below:

```
install.packages('devtools')
library(devtools)
install_github("RGoogleDocs", "duncantl")
library(RGoogleDocs)
```