# Trying to access files from Google Drive folders using R

Tags: r, google-docs, r-package, r-googlesheets

I am a beginner in R and I am trying to access google sheets on Google drive using R. Package `googlesheets` is one way of accessing the google sheets, but with this I am only able to download, edit or upload files to the 'My Drive' folder on google drive. Instead, my main aim is to access files from some particular folder on Google drive other than the 'My Drive'. Could someone throw light on this.

Also I tried to experiment with `RGoogleDocs` package but couldn't even install that package as it is not available in any repository for version R 3.2.3.

Comment: using `googlesheets`, you can access a sheet by it's url or key. Have you tried that? Can you show us the code that did not work?

Comment: Yeah. I tried using googlesheets, with which I only can create or access files from My Drive path. But I want to access files from Folders inside My Drive path.

Comment: Here is an answer to how install RGoogleDocs
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37575563/trying-to-install-rgoogledocs-package